# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I try to get `jMethodID` of the method in the java code ,but when I call this particular function, that does that an exception is thrown :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: displayKeyStrokes
at org.suhail.keylogger.HelperClasses.NativeMethods.initializeJNIVars(Native Method)
at org.suhail.keylogger.GUI.MainGUI.jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(MainGUI.java:356)
.
.
.
```

I do not understand the reason for this. Following is the *C* code snippet that gets called from the java method :

```
void Java_org_suhail_keylogger_HelperClasses_NativeMethods_initializeJNIVars
(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
 jclass cls = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env,obj);
 callBackToDeliverKeyStroke = (*env)->GetMethodID(env,cls,"displayKeyStrokes","()V");
 object = (*env)->NewGlobalRef(env,obj);
 if(object == NULL | callBackToDeliverKeyStroke == NULL | cls == NULL) {
    printf("Initialization error...One of the variable is Null\n");
 }
}
```

And this is the method named `displayKeyStrokes` in the java code :

```
 public void displayKeyStrokes() {
    System.out.println("Java Message : A Key has been pressed");
}
```

What could be the reason I am getting an exception ?

### EDIT :

Java Code that calls JNI Code :

```
    private void jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    jMenuItem1.setEnabled(false);
    jMenuItem2.setEnabled(true);
    try {
       System.loadLibrary("Dll_PKeylogger"); // Load the dll written to listen to the tapping of keys
       nativeMethods.initializeJNIVars(); // CALL
    }catch(Exception exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

*NativeMethods Class* (declares the native methods)

```
package org.suhail.keylogger.HelperClasses;

public class NativeMethods {

 public native void initializeJNIVars();
 public native void unregisterHook(); 

}
```

***NOTE :*** I am calling the method `initializeJNIVars` on the object of another class named `NativeMethods` and the method `jMenuItem1ActionPerformed` is called from an anonymous inner class whenever an event occurs as :

```
        jMenuItem1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please extend your Java snippet to include the beginning of the Java class declaration and the declaration of the native method (in addition to displayKeyStrokes)

Comment: Are you sure that you're passing the correct jclass for this method? Also, are you really trying to make a key logger program?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I think so. I have added to the question. yeah I am trying a kind of..

Comment: Is your `jMenuItem1ActionPerformed` method in the same class as the `displayKeyStrokes` method? Be sure to check regarding inner classes as well before answering this.

Comment: And regarding, `"yeah I am trying a kind of..."` shame on you.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels shame ? why ?

Comment: These types of programs are often used as snoopware, spyware.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels If my sole purpose was to snoop I would have _bought_ a sophisticated keylogger . My sole aim here is to improve my understanding of jni

Comment: You still haven't addressed my question in the 5th comment to this question. Myself, I'd use JNA to do this sort of stuff. It's a lot easier, at least for me.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels `jMenuItem1ActionPerformed` is called from an anonymous class which is inside the same class as `displayKeyStrokes`. And yes `jMenuItem1ActionPerformed` is in the same class as `displayKeyStrokes` except it is called from anonymous inner class as shown [here](http://i46.tinypic.com/21oug3k.jpg)

Comment: That's likely your problem then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You state:

> jMenuItem1ActionPerformed is called from an anonymous class which is inside the same class as displayKeyStrokes. And yes jMenuItem1ActionPerformed is in the same class as jMenuItem1ActionPerformed except it is called from anonymous inner class as shown here

That's likely your problem then. The jMenuItem1ActionPerformed being in an anonymous inner class is important and means that it is in a different class from jMenuItem1ActionPerformed, and that this will need to be taken into account when you try to get the method ID from your JNI C code.

Consider giving your `initializeJNIVars()` method a parameter that takes an instance of the outer class, and then pass that instance into the parameter and use it when you call `GetMethodID(...)`. Note that you will have to pass the parameter in as `OuterClassName.this`.

Comment: The method is not inside the anonymous inner class but is called from there whenever an event occurs.So JNI C snippet will be seeing the call as from a function,in the same class as `displayKeyStrokes`. can you explain this

Comment: and I am calling the method `initializeJNIVars` on an object of class written as a separate module.I have mentioned this in my question.I just tried shifting the method `displayKeyStrokes` in that class (`NativeMethods`) and I didn't see the exception though the JVM crashed.

Comment: I haven't been able to get over the problem. Can we please discuss here @ http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17557/discussion-between-hovercraft-full-of-eels-and-suhail-gupta

Answer (score 0):

The description of the exception you get is:

> Thrown if an application tries to call a specified method of a class
>   (either static or instance), and that class no longer has a definition
>   of that method.
>
> Normally, this error is caught by the compiler; this error can only
>   occur at run time if the definition of a class has incompatibly
>   changed.

Is your code thread separated? is there any chance the displayKeyStrokes method is loaded by a thread that is already dead when you try to call this method?